# www and non-www pointing to different places

Tags: domain-name-system

I have set up a domain in directadmin for about 3 days now, and I get really strange results. When I browser to my domain using www.mydomain.com I get the website I uploaded, but when I just type mydomain.com I end up on some parked domain of dnsmadeeasy.com.

I have done everything correct I think. I made the following records

```
mydomain.com    A        1.2.3.4      (A record pointing to my domain)  
www             CNAME    mydomain.com (created a CNAME for the www subdomain)
```

And I created the right NS records pointing to my nameservers.

Anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made any additions to or deletions from your hosts file?

Have you flushed your DNS cache?

(if you can provide the domain name, that would be quite helpful)

Comment: And don't forget to flush the browser cache as well.

Comment: Yes it was the browser cache!

Answer (score 0):

You should use an nslookup tool (like Windows version here) to perform some first-level troubleshooting. Verify from your local computer you can resolve the correct IP address from your current ISP DNS servers. In my case, i am tracking down my domain icelava.net

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>nslookup
Default Server:  dnscache2.singnet.com.sg
Address:  165.21.100.88

> icelava.net
Server:  dnscache2.singnet.com.sg
Address:  165.21.100.88

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    icelava.net
Address:  70.85.20.8

> www.icelava.net
Server:  dnscache2.singnet.com.sg
Address:  165.21.100.88

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.icelava.net
Address:  70.85.20.8
```

If you have set a CNAME record and is properly propagated, the local DNS server would be able to reply knowing it's an alias

```
> web.icelava.net
Server:  dnscache2.singnet.com.sg
Address:  165.21.100.88

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.icelava.net
Address:  70.85.20.8
Aliases:  web.icelava.net
```

If it does not seem right I'd convert the query type to NS to determine what are the nameservers authoritative for my domain

```
> set type=ns
> icelava.net
Server:  dnscache2.singnet.com.sg
Address:  165.21.100.88

Non-authoritative answer:
icelava.net     nameserver = ns4.nameresolve.com
icelava.net     nameserver = ns1.nameresolve.com
icelava.net     nameserver = ns3.nameresolve.com
icelava.net     nameserver = ns2.nameresolve.com

ns2.nameresolve.com     internet address = 63.251.83.88
ns3.nameresolve.com     internet address = 63.251.171.92
ns4.nameresolve.com     internet address = 64.94.31.66
```

If the nameservers do not match the nameserver(s) whose zone file you are editing, I suggest contacting your DNS administrator/provider for more technical details.

Comment: +1 Nice method, this is sure helpful. Unfortunately it was just a browser cache problem.

Comment: good that it's a simple issue.